# How to pass multiple parameters in sql query using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have sql query which is shown below its a select statement I want to pass dynamically the values but I am not aware how can we do it .here I want to pass product and location dynamically
can anyone help in this ..

```
public static ResultSet RetrieveData() throws Exception {
    
        PreparedStatement statement;
    
         String sql = "select * FROM Courses WHERE "
                    + "product = product? "
                    + "and location = location? ";
         System.out.println(sql);
         DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver());
    
         String mysqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wave1_build";
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlUrl, "root", "root");
        statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        return rs;
```

Comment: Too many problems.  First, fix the query and get something valid in there, then come back with other questions.

Comment: Ok , Now I have edited its I think fine , pls check now

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use plain `?` placeholders along with the appropriate setters to bind values:

```sql
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Courses WHERE product = ? AND location = ?";
statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1, "some product");
statement.setString(2, "some location");

// NOTE: executeQuery() when used with prepared statements does NOT take any parameters
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```